# Java X509EncodedKeySpec in C#

Tags: java, c#, x509

I have code sample in Java and I need the same functionality in C#. Are there any alternatives to the classes, which are used for the sample?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

publicKey = publicKey.replaceAll("-----(BEGIN|END).*", "").trim();

X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(publicKey));
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
PublicKey pKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);

Signature ecdsaSign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
ecdsaSign.initVerify(pKey);
ecdsaSign.update(stringToVerify.getBytes("UTF-8"));

if (ecdsaSign.verify(new BigInteger(ECDSA, 16).toByteArray())) {
    // true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not anything in .NET (by itself) which can read the public key structure only.  But if you can get the entirety of a certificate then you can write the following in .NET 4.6.1:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class DemoClass
    {
        public static bool ECDsaSha256Verify(string pemCert, string data, byte[] signature)
        {
            using (var cert = new X509Certificate2(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pemCert)))
            using (ECDsa ecdsa = cert.GetECDsaPublicKey())
            {
                if (ecdsa == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Certificate does not have an ECDSA key.");
                }

                byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                return ecdsa.VerifyData(dataBytes, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wasn't sure where your BigInteger signature value was coming from, so that I have just left as a byte array.

Comment: is there something similar for .net4.5?

Comment: @petriq Not really, the GetECDsaPublicKey (extension) method was first added in 4.6.1.  4.6.1 released 18 months ago, so you should hopefully be able to depend on it.

Comment: I have decided to use BouncyCastle library instead which works for me.